# Crash in MFMailComposeView

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I'm obviously missing something in my code, because any time I try to press "Send" or "Cancel" the app crashes.  Also, I have a set subject and torecipient, but if I try to edit them, the app crashes.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here's my current code relating to MFMailComposeViewController:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"BSCApp@ymail.com"]];
    [controller setSubject:@"My Subject"];
    if (controller) [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
```

and...

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result 
                    error:(NSError*)error;
{
    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
        NSLog(@"It's away!");
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `autorelease` and `release` on the same instance, so you're over-releasing it and later when you try to do anything with it, you get a crash for accessing a zombie object.

Remove the `autorelease` message from first line and it will be fine.

Comment: Perfect!  It works beautifully now :). I had tried removing the autorelease before, but it kept failing because I still had 3 brackets even after I removed the release.  Thanks for the quick reply!  Will accept your answer when it lets me...